# Value count operation on Python returning weird information?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analyzing a dataset about commemorative plaques around the world. I first figured out the number of plaques per 'type' of subject (man, woman, place, group, thing, or animal) and then wanted to figure out which countries had the most plaques describing women. This was my code:

```
gendercount = plaques['lead_subject_type'].value_counts()
women = plaques.loc[(plaques['lead_subject_type'] == 'woman')]
women['country'].value_counts()
```

Although the gendercount shows that [there are 3465 plaques dedicated to women](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsIG1.png), my last line of code returns [values that don't add up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNXwe.png). What am I doing wrong? (P.S., I'm a beginner, so please explain in detail so I can learn better!)

Comment: Do you get different results with `women['country'].value_counts(dropna=False)`?

Comment: @DaveCosta nope :(

Comment: Could you provide us a piece of your dataset or a sample dataset that we can use to recreate the problem?

Comment: What you're doing looks correct.  Looks like you are using Jupyter. It is possible to get confusing results by not recalculating all cells.  Might be worth doing a clear-and-run-all to see if that changes anything.

Comment: @DaveCosta Ahhh! This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

value_counts does not return nulls by default. So if you are selecting the country attribute, rows with country = null will not be counted